# Laravel Eloquent cannot assign a value to the model's relation property

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am unable to assign a value to a model's property

```
App\person::find(1)->plan
```

This command gives me something like this in artisan tinker

```
     id: 1,
     name: "name",
     description:"",
```

I am trying to specify a value for `description`

```
App\person::find(1)->plan->description='something'
```

It outputs

```
'something'
```

But it's not saving it in the description, I still get this

```
     id: 1,
     name: "name",
     description:"",
```

I tried several commands, none work

```
App\person::find(1)->plan->description='something'->save();
App\person::find(1)->plan->description->save('something');
```

Am I doing it wrong? Yes, the model's property has been set to `fillable`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To save you have to

```
$person= App\person::find(1);
$person->plan->description='something';
$person->plan->save();
```

Or if you need a one liner do

```
App\person::find(1)->plan->fill(['description' => 'something')->save();
```

.

The way you did will try to execute save on a string:

```
App\person::find(1)->plan->description='something'->save();
```

Comment: Tried App\person::find(1)->plan->fill(['description' => 'something')->save(); ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$plan = App\person::find(1)->plan;
$plan->description = 'something';
$plan->save();
```